how to use Vue Router's Relative redirecting (not working)?
i am learning Relative redirecting from Vue router Doc.
and i am tring to implement the doc example of the code.
const routes = [
  {
    // will always redirect /users/123/posts to /users/123/profile
    path: '/users/:id/posts',
    redirect: to => {
      // the function receives the target route as the argument
      // a relative location doesn't start with `/`
      // or { path: 'profile'}
      return 'profile'
    },
  },
]

in my realize of the code .
it  says when the link path is /users/123/posts
the finally redirect path will be  /users/123/profile not /profile.
So the same url of my code path :
http://localhost:5173/maxroll-build/S/roll >> http://localhost:5173/maxroll-build/S/roll
but the real path finally is http://localhost:5173/gg
I tried my way for a long time. Among them, I found a question that was almost exactly the same as mine (Relative redirecting bug #1902).
but i am still not totally realize how to write a Relative redirecting. is there any code demo?
or maybe the Doc still  ambiguity ?
my code:
// router/index.js

const routes = [
// ... other route
{ 
    path: "/maxroll-build/:buildLevel/roll",
    redirect: (to) => {
      console.log("to ", to);
      // console of to.fullPath: "/maxroll-build/S/roll"
      return { path: "gg" }; // here finally web link: http://localhost:5173/gg
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/maxroll-build/:buildLevel/gg",
    component: MaxRollLevel,
  },
// ... other route
];

